# How do I look up a foreign object in a Class view by a slug contained in the url?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, slug

model.py:

```
class A():
    contents N/A
class B():
    keyToA = model.ForeignKey("A")
    somefield = TextField()
```

View example url: localhost/model-A-object-slug/ calls BCreateForm (below)

form.py:

```
class BCreateForm(CreateView):
    model = B
    form_class = modelfactory_form(B, form=BCreateForm, field=("somefield"))
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.KeyToA = getAFromSlugInURL
        ....
```

How do I fill in `form.instance.KeyToA` given the slug in the view's url?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your model definitions are wrong and prevent you from doing what you want. Trying to see through the unnecessary obfuscation you have added to your question, you apparently  want to get an instance of A by a slug in B. But the relationship from A to B is many-to-one, so there are *many* A instances related to the item in B with that slug.

Comment: "But the relationship from A to B is many-to-one" Can you please clarify this? I thought my models were setup so that the relationship from A to B is one-to-many.

Comment: No idea how. A ForeignKey is a one-to-many relationship, where the model that contains the FK field is the many side of the relationship.